# Connecting to mercurial repository with smartgit: how to register changed password?

Tags: mercurial, smartgit

I have been successfully using SmartGit to access a Mercurial repository. My password on the server hosting Mercurial has recently changed. My SmartGit project now fails authentication (Message: "abort: authorization failed" on attempting to Push changes). I can't see any way to register a new password.

(Read access from the repository is working fine. It only fails on push.)

I found advice to go to Preferences>Authentication and remove the existing "Known credentials". However my credentials for this repository aren't listed there. It lists a number of Github repositories that I use, but not this Mercurial repository.

*FURTHER INFORMATION 2014-03-04*

Opened the keychain application in Applications/utilities. Tried to modify the password for the relevant web domain. No success.

Tried to delete the entry for the relevant web domain. No success.

Tried to clone a new repository from the master, and push from that. No success.

Discovered and upgraded to SmartGit/HG 5.0.7. No success. But it does give more detailed output, reproduced here:

```
Push
    ...
        url, req, headers)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mercurial/url.py", line 431, in http_error_auth_reqed
        self, auth_header, host, req, headers)
      File "/var/folders/zf/wthbvqt14q53jh5n3clx1yqw0000gn/T/smartgit550802704160068758tmp/smartgit_http-0.py", line 56, in basic_http_error_auth_reqed
        return basic_http_error_auth_reqed.orig(self, authreq, host, req, headers)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 872, in http_error_auth_reqed
        response = self.retry_http_basic_auth(host, req, realm)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 885, in retry_http_basic_auth
        return self.parent.open(req, timeout=req.timeout)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
        response = meth(req, response)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
        'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 442, in error
        result = self._call_chain(*args)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
        result = func(*args)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 897, in http_error_401
        url, req, headers)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mercurial/url.py", line 431, in http_error_auth_reqed
        self, auth_header, host, req, headers)
      File "/var/folders/zf/wthbvqt14q53jh5n3clx1yqw0000gn/T/smartgit550802704160068758tmp/smartgit_http-0.py", line 56, in basic_http_error_auth_reqed
        return basic_http_error_auth_reqed.orig(self, authreq, host, req, headers)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 872, in http_error_auth_reqed
        response = self.retry_http_basic_auth(host, req, realm)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 885, in retry_http_basic_auth
        return self.parent.open(req, timeout=req.timeout)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
        response = meth(req, response)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
        'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 442, in error
        result = self._call_chain(*args)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
        result = func(*args)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 897, in http_error_401
        url, req, headers)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mercurial/url.py", line 431, in http_error_auth_reqed
        self, auth_header, host, req, headers)
      File "/var/folders/zf/wthbvqt14q53jh5n3clx1yqw0000gn/T/smartgit550802704160068758tmp/smartgit_http-0.py", line 56, in basic_http_error_auth_reqed
        return basic_http_error_auth_reqed.orig(self, authreq, host, req, headers)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 872, in http_error_auth_reqed
        response = self.retry_http_basic_auth(host, req, realm)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 885, in retry_http_basic_auth
        return self.parent.open(req, timeout=req.timeout)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
        response = meth(req, response)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
        'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 442, in error
        result = self._call_chain(*args)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
        result = func(*args)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 897, in http_error_401
        url, req, headers)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mercurial/url.py", line 431, in http_error_auth_reqed
        self, auth_header, host, req, headers)
      File "/var/folders/zf/wthbvqt14q53jh5n3clx1yqw0000gn/T/smartgit550802704160068758tmp/smartgit_http-0.py", line 56, in basic_http_error_auth_reqed
        return basic_http_error_auth_reqed.orig(self, authreq, host, req, headers)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 872, in http_error_auth_reqed
        response = self.retry_http_basic_auth(host, req, realm)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 885, in retry_http_basic_auth
        return self.parent.open(req, timeout=req.timeout)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
        response = meth(req, response)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
        'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 442, in error
        result = self._call_chain(*args)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
        result = func(*args)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 897, in http_error_401
        url, req, headers)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mercurial/url.py", line 431, in http_error_auth_reqed
        self, auth_header, host, req, headers)
      File "/var/folders/zf/wthbvqt14q53jh5n3clx1yqw0000gn/T/smartgit550802704160068758tmp/smartgit_http-0.py", line 56, in basic_http_error_auth_reqed
        return basic_http_error_auth_reqed.orig(self, authreq, host, req, headers)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 872, in http_error_auth_reqed
        response = self.retry_http_basic_auth(host, req, realm)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 885, in retry_http_basic_auth
        return self.parent.open(req, timeout=req.timeout)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
        response = meth(req, response)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
        'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 442, in error
        result = self._call_chain(*args)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
        result = func(*args)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 897, in http_error_401
        url, req, headers)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mercurial/url.py", line 431, in http_error_auth_reqed
        self, auth_header, host, req, headers)
      File "/var/folders/zf/wthbvqt14q53jh5n3clx1yqw0000gn/T/smartgit550802704160068758tmp/smartgit_http-0.py", line 58, in basic_http_error_auth_reqed
        call_smartgit("fail", host, self.passwd.ui)
      File "/var/folders/zf/wthbvqt14q53jh5n3clx1yqw0000gn/T/smartgit550802704160068758tmp/smartgit_http-0.py", line 38, in call_smartgit
        command, authuri])
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 575, in check_output
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/Volumes/SmartGitHg 5.0.7.1/SmartGitHg 5.app/Contents/Resources/Plugins/JRE/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java', '-cp', '/Volumes/SmartGitHg 5.0.7.1/SmartGitHg 5.app/Contents/Resources/Java/log4j.jar:/Volumes/SmartGitHg 5.0.7.1/SmartGitHg 5.app/Contents/Resources/Java/smartgit.jar:/Volumes/SmartGitHg 5.0.7.1/SmartGitHg 5.app/Contents/Resources/Java/trilead.jar', '-Dsmartgit.port=4333', '-Dsmartgit.tempDir=/var/folders/zf/wthbvqt14q53jh5n3clx1yqw0000gn/T/smartgit550802704160068758tmp', '-Dsmartgit.id=7259439108629017519', 'com.syntevo.hgapp.file.state.transport.ShHttpMain', 'fail', 'https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/xslt30-test?cmd=unbundle']' returned non-zero exit status 255
Push: warning: dvcs.w3.org certificate with fingerprint 97:4c:0e:c5:2e:95:74:5e:c7:fa:ed:07:3f:97:ab:ea:80:7a:be:7c not verified (check hostfingerprints or web.cacerts config setting) warning: dvcs.w3.org certificate with fingerprint 97:4c:0e:c5:2e:95:74:5e:c7:fa:ed:07:3f:97:ab:ea:80:7a:be:7c not verified (check hostfingerprints or web.cacerts config setting) warning: dvcs.w3.org certificate with fingerprint 97:4c:0e:c5:2e:95:74:5e:c7:fa:ed:07:3f:97:ab:ea:80:7a:be:7c not verified (check hostfingerprints or web.cacerts config setting) warning: dvcs.w3.org certificate with fingerprint 97:4c:0e:c5:2e:95:74:5e:c7:fa:ed:07:3f:97:ab:ea:80:7a:be:7c not verified (check hostfingerprints or web.cacerts config setting) warning: dvcs.w3.org certificate with fingerprint 97:4c:0e:c5:2e:95:74:5e:c7:fa:ed:07:3f:97:ab:ea:80:7a:be:7c not verified (check hostfingerprints or web.cacerts config setting) warning: dvcs.w3.org certificate with fingerprint 97:4c:0e:c5:2e:95:74:5e:c7:fa:ed:07:3f:97:ab:ea:80:7a:be:7c not verified (check hostfingerprints or web.cacerts config setting) warning: dvcs.w3.org certificate with fingerprint 97:4c:0e:c5:2e:95:74:5e:c7:fa:ed:07:3f:97:ab:ea:80:7a:be:7c not verified (check hostfingerprints or web.cacerts config setting) abort: authorization failed
    $ hg push --config extensions.smartgit_http=/var/folders/zf/wthbvqt14q53jh5n3clx1yqw0000gn/T/smartgit550802704160068758tmp/smartgit_http-0.py --config "smartgit.classpath=/Volumes/SmartGitHg 5.0.7.1/SmartGitHg 5.app/Contents/Resources/Java/log4j.jar:/Volumes/SmartGitHg 5.0.7.1/SmartGitHg 5.app/Contents/Resources/Java/smartgit.jar:/Volumes/SmartGitHg 5.0.7.1/SmartGitHg 5.app/Contents/Resources/Java/trilead.jar" --config smartgit.id=882717487546533434 --config "smartgit.java=/Volumes/SmartGitHg 5.0.7.1/SmartGitHg 5.app/Contents/Resources/Plugins/JRE/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java" --config smartgit.mainClass=com.syntevo.hgapp.file.state.transport.ShHttpMain --config smartgit.port=4333 --config smartgit.tempDir=/var/folders/zf/wthbvqt14q53jh5n3clx1yqw0000gn/T/smartgit550802704160068758tmp --config ui.ssh=smartssh.sh --config extensions.color=! --rev 3fd788a6f541d7514e73920288528456b317a5ab default
    dvcs.w3.org certificate with fingerprint 97:4c:0e:c5:2e:95:74:5e:c7:fa:ed:07:3f:97:ab:ea:80:7a:be:7c not verified (check hostfingerprints or web.cacerts config setting)
    pushing to https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/xslt30-test
    searching for changes
    dvcs.w3.org certificate with fingerprint 97:4c:0e:c5:2e:95:74:5e:c7:fa:ed:07:3f:97:ab:ea:80:7a:be:7c not verified (check hostfingerprints or web.cacerts config setting)
    7 changesets found
    dvcs.w3.org certificate with fingerprint 97:4c:0e:c5:2e:95:74:5e:c7:fa:ed:07:3f:97:ab:ea:80:7a:be:7c not verified (check hostfingerprints or web.cacerts config setting)
    dvcs.w3.org certificate with fingerprint 97:4c:0e:c5:2e:95:74:5e:c7:fa:ed:07:3f:97:ab:ea:80:7a:be:7c not verified (check hostfingerprints or web.cacerts config setting)
    dvcs.w3.org certificate with fingerprint 97:4c:0e:c5:2e:95:74:5e:c7:fa:ed:07:3f:97:ab:ea:80:7a:be:7c not verified (check hostfingerprints or web.cacerts config setting)
    dvcs.w3.org certificate with fingerprint 97:4c:0e:c5:2e:95:74:5e:c7:fa:ed:07:3f:97:ab:ea:80:7a:be:7c not verified (check hostfingerprints or web.cacerts config setting)
    dvcs.w3.org certificate with fingerprint 97:4c:0e:c5:2e:95:74:5e:c7:fa:ed:07:3f:97:ab:ea:80:7a:be:7c not verified (check hostfingerprints or web.cacerts config setting)
    abort: authorization failed
```

Comment: Are you using SSH or HTTP access?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.

There is a configuration file called .hgrc in the user home directory. This contains the password used for access to the remote repository (in clear!). You can edit the file to use the new password instead, and everything works again.

Comment: Note, that Mercurial itself seems to store the password there (not SmartGit).